# Is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore that slow on Android?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin.android, entity-framework-core

I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0 with Xamarin.Android and I have to add more than 400000 items to a SQLite database but I found the process of doing that is very slow. For example, just to add 1024 items takes between 3 and 4 seconds.

The problem I have is that I don't know if I am doing something wrong, or there is a better way to accomplish this task (any advice on any optimization will be very welcome). Are this times the best performance we can accomplish in this scenario?

My idea is to process/insert the 400000 items by batches of 1024 but with this performance and doing some conservative math it will take more than 20 minutes to process all items, and this time is way up unacceptable. I have been trying with different batches sizes but performances do not improve.

In order to see what happens I created some simple benchmark code and here is my approach:

This is the entity I'm using:

```
    public sealed class BenchmarkEntityPoint
    {
        public BenchmarkEntityPoint()
        {
        }

        public BenchmarkEntityPoint(long field1, double field2, double field3, double field4, double field5, double field6, double field7, double field8)
        {
            Field1 = field1;
            Field2 = field2;
            Field3 = field3;
            Field4 = field4;
            Field5 = field5;
            Field6 = field6;
            Field7 = field7;
            Field8 = field8;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public long Field1 { get; set; }

        public double Field2 { get; internal set; }

        public double Field3 { get; internal set; }

        public double Field4 { get; internal set; }

        public double Field5 { get; internal set; }

        public double Field6 { get; internal set; }

        public double Field7 { get; internal set; }

        public double Field8 { get; internal set; }
    }
```

This is my DbContext:

```
    public sealed class BenchmarkContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly string path;

        public BenchmarkContext(string path)
        {
            this.path = path;
            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<BenchmarkEntityPoint> BenchmarkEntityPoints { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<BenchmarkEntityPoint>().HasIndex(arg => arg.Field1);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={path}");
        }
    }
```

... and in some Activity, I have the following testing method

```
        private void OnBenchmarkStart(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var benchmarkPath = Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "EFCBENCHMARKS", "benchmark1");
            var context = // create the context

            var points = // generate 1024 points to test

            var mark = DateTimeOffset.Now;

            context.BenchmarkEntityPoints.AddRange(points);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var elapsed = (DateTimeOffset.Now - mark).TotalMilliseconds;
            // always getting between 3 and 4 sencods
        }
```

Comment: There are trade-offs with using ORMs, and this is one of them. Last time I used EF for processing over 200,000 records it took eight hours. I could have significantly reduced the time by using ADO.NET, but convenience was more important.

Comment: Have you tried disabling change tracking when doing the bulk insert? Set `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to false and don't forget to set it back to true when you're done.

Comment: For the fastest way to insert data into SQLite, see my post [Bulk Insert in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](http://www.bricelam.net/2017/07/20/sqlite-bulk-insert.html).